# Upgrade TFS SQL Server Data tier using new hardware

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We are currently running a TFS 2017 Deployment with a SQL 2014 SP2 Standard edition Instance on another server. To prepare for the TFS 2018 version we need to update to SQL 2016.

The SQL Server team prefers to do this using new hardware where SQL 2016 **Enterprise** is installed.
Where this seemed an "easy" task, i now find this comment in the documentation

> Step 2: Install and configure SQL Server on
>   the new hardware To restore data for Team Foundation, you must install
>   SQL Server on the computer to which you want to move the databases for
>   Team Foundation Server. **The version of SQL Server that you install
>   must exactly match the version on the original server that hosted the
>   databases**. This requirement includes the service-pack level, the
>   collation settings, and the language edition. If the match is not
>   exact, you might not be able to restore the data, or Team Foundation
>   Server might not operate correctly even if you can restore the data.
>
> Install SQL Server in the new environment, prepare SQL Server for
>   restoration of data for Team Foundation, and make sure that it is
>   operational. As an alternative, create an instance of SQL Server on a
>   server that already has a matching version installed.
>
> For more information, see Install get started.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops#step-2-install-and-configure-sql-server-on-the-new-hardware

How serious is this comment and is there no official way to upgrade the SQL Server instance using new hardware ? Or should we install 2014 Sp2 on the new hardware, move the database and still do an in-place upgrade on the new host ?

Looking forward to your comments

Comment: Have you considered moving your TFS to dev.azure.com. Then you never have to worry about hardware or software upgrades again

Comment: Well that's not up for discussion now. Hope someone can advise on this particular upgrade that is scheduled

Comment: Enterprise vs Standard is highly unlikely to be a problem. Why don't you do a trial migration and see if it upgrades. There's probably no problem. You can also install multiple instances of SQL Server on one host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running TFS 2017 Update 2, migrating the databases from SQL 2014 SP2 Standard to SQL 2016 SP2 Enterprise completed without any issues.